# No keyboard input AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, keyboard-input

So I'm trying to get keyboard input from the user to move a character. It works in another program that I was using, and I copy pasted, but it isn't working in this one. It gives me `Line 87, Column 38   1119: Access of possibly undefined property EVENT_FRAME through a reference with static type Class.` I can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

This is the buttonClick function that is used to when I hit the start button.

```
    public function buttonClick(ev:MouseEvent):void
    {
        createGameScreen();
        this.mcLink.gotoAndPlay("Idle");
        this.mcLink.x=50;
        this.mcLink.y=200;
        this.mcLink.scaleX=this.mcLink.scaleY=3;
        this.stage.addEventListener(Event.EVENT_FRAME, this.enterFrameHandler, false, 0, true);
    }
```

This is the event handler function for the keyboard input.

```
public function enterFrameHandler($e:Event):void
    {
        if (this.mcLink)
        {               
            if (KeyboardManager.instance.isKeyDown(KeyCode.DOWN))
            {
                if (this.mcLink.y + this.mcLink.height > this.stage.stageHeight || this.mcLink.y - this.mcLink.height <= 0)
                {
                    this.mcLink.y += -15;
                    mcLink.gotoAndPlay("Idle");
                    return;
                }
                this.mcLink.y += _nHeroMovementSpeed;
                mcLink.gotoAndPlay("Down");
            }
            else if (KeyboardManager.instance.isKeyDown(KeyCode.UP))
            {
                if (this.mcLink.y + this.mcLink.height > this.stage.stageHeight || this.mcLink.y - this.mcLink.height <= 0)
                {
                    this.mcLink.y += 15;
                    mcLink.gotoAndPlay("Idle");
                    return;
                }
                this.mcLink.y -= _nHeroMovementSpeed;
                mcLink.gotoAndPlay("Up");
            }

            if (KeyboardManager.instance.isKeyDown(KeyCode.LEFT))
            {
                if (this.mcLink.x + this.mcLink.width > this.stage.stageWidth || this.mcLink.x - this.mcLink.width <= 0) 
                {
                    this.mcLink.x += 15;
                    mcLink.gotoAndPlay("Idle");
                    return;
                }                   
                this.mcLink.x -= _nHeroMovementSpeed;
                mcLink.gotoAndPlay("Left");

            }
            else if (KeyboardManager.instance.isKeyDown(KeyCode.RIGHT))
            {   
                if (this.mcLink.x + this.mcLink.width > this.stage.stageWidth || this.mcLink.x - this.mcLink.width <= 0) 
                {
                    this.mcLink.x += -15;
                    mcLink.gotoAndPlay("Idle");
                    return;
                }
                this.mcLink.x += _nHeroMovementSpeed;
                mcLink.gotoAndPlay("Right");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean [`Event.ENTER_FRAME`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#ENTER_FRAME)?

```
this.stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, this.enterFrameHandler, false, 0, true);
//                                ^^^^^^^^^^^ EVENT_FRAME isn't a known Event.
```

Comment: This particular line of code is working in the other program, that is almost identical to what I'm working on now. I'm not sure if it's in the package that our teacher provided